# Firebase realtime database query fails due to security rules after user authenticates, works otherwise

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

After a user signs in, my app loads their data from a database that has the following structure:

- `archivedOrders`
  -- `$orderId`
  --- `ownedByUser`
  --- `some other data`

The read is triggered by the standard auth state change handler:

```
handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
    if (user == nil) { //User signed out
        AuthService.shared.signInAsAnonymous()
    } else {
        self.clearData()
        archivedOrdersRef.removeAllObservers()

        let archivedOrdersQuery = archivedOrdersRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "ownedByUser").queryEqual(toValue: user.uid).queryLimited(toLast: 25)
        archivedOrdersQuery.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in ...some code here...
        })
```

The rules for this node are the following:

```
"archivedOrders": {
  ".write": "auth != null",
  ".read": "(query.orderByChild == 'ownedByUser' && query.equalTo == auth.uid) || 
            (query.orderByChild == 'restaurantId')",
```

Everything works fine when I start the app when the user is already authenticated. But if the user signs in during runtime, I get no data and the console gives the following message:

```
Listener at /archivedOrders failed: permission_denied
```

Almost looks like the database rules' auth doesn't know that the user is authenticated with new credentials and should be able to query the node.

Strangely enough, if I try refreshing the token and wrap the subscription code in

```
    user!.getIDTokenForcingRefresh(true, completion: { (token, error) in
        [subscription code]
    })
```

I still get the error message in the console, but the data arrives.

Shouldn't the user already be authenticated in the `stateDidChangeListener`, so that the rules know that the reads should be allowed? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If it works when the user is already signed in, then clearly your rules and your code match up. The only reason I can think of for the error message in that case, is that you're attaching the listener when the user isn't signed in yet, or that the user is signed out after the listener has been attached. I'd check your entire app flow for cases where this may happen.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I would think that too, however the query gets triggered by the auth state change handler. There is no way that the user is not signed in (unless I misunderstood the purpose of the handler) or that the user gets signed out in the meantime (as can be seen in the code snippet). Even adding a simple 1-sec delay causes the data to be read. Same problem exists for the Android version of the app.

Comment: Hmm... that one second delay sounds really suspicious. I've never seen auth state take time to propagate beyond the auth state listener. Essentially your listener is only invoked *after* the state has propagated, which is precisely why you want to use a listener to begin with. It could be a bug of course. Can you [enable debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/Database#setloggingenabled_) and check the wire traffic to see if it hints at a race condition on setting auth state and attaching the query?